# Control the Ford C-MAX 2011 speed limiter via software

Tags: ford

I am the owner of a Ford C-MAX 2011 and my current dream is to be able to set the speed limiter from any possible hardware device (arduino / raspberry / bluetooth / other).

The final aim would be to write some code that is able to set the speed limiter automatically according to data from Waze / Google Maps / Sygic / Anything else.

I can code so there should be no problems with implementation, I am more investigating if it is doable and which hardware / software I can use.

Is there a way to obtain this result?

Comment: Given how many other checks are made by the cruise control system, I suggest you don't interfere.

Comment: And given the requirement that automotive software is governed by strict codes of practice (such as MISRA) you might well be infringing the construction & use regulations, or making a mod that invalidates the insurance.

Comment: You could ask a pro tuner to investigate although as others here have said whilst technically it may be possible there could be plenty of issues.  I do like your thinking here - how about a heads up display onto the windshield showing the current speed limit from a navigation app ?

Comment: I am just talking about setting the speed limiter, nothing more / nothing less.
The speed limiter is designed so that if user inputs anything (brake / accelerator) it is automatically bypassed.
And, also, doesn't accelerate automatically.
It just prevents you from going faster than X km/h (unless you push the pedal, clearly).